# Why does AdaBoost not work with DecisionTree?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, adaboost

I'm using sklearn 0.19.1 with DecisionTree and AdaBoost.

I have a DecisionTree classifier that works fine:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

train_split_perc = 10000
test_split_perc = pdf.shape[0] - train_split_perc

train_pdf_x = pdf[:train_split_perc]
train_pdf_y = YY[:train_split_perc]

test_pdf_x = pdf[-test_split_perc:]
test_pdf_y = YY[-test_split_perc:]

clf.fit(train_pdf_x, train_pdf_y)

pred2 = clf.predict(test_pdf_x)
```

But when trying to add AdaBoost, it throws an error on the predict function:

```
treeclf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3)
adaclf = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=treeclf, n_estimators=500, learning_rate=0.5)

train_split_perc = 10000
test_split_perc = pdf.shape[0] - train_split_perc

train_pdf_x = pdf[:train_split_perc]
train_pdf_y = YY[:train_split_perc]

test_pdf_x = pdf[-test_split_perc:]
test_pdf_y = YY[-test_split_perc:]

adaclf.fit(train_pdf_x, train_pdf_y)

pred2 = adaclf.predict(test_pdf_x)
```

Specifically the error says:

`ValueError: bad input shape (236821, 6)`

The dataset that it seems to be pointing to is `train_pdf_y` because it has a shape of `(236821, 6)` and I don't understand why.

From even the description of the AdaBoostClassifier [in the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier) I can understand that the actual classifier that uses the data is the DecisionTree:

> An AdaBoost [1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier) classifier is a meta-estimator that begins by fitting
>   a classifier on the original dataset and then fits additional copies
>   of the classifier on the same dataset but where the weights of
>   incorrectly classified instances are adjusted such that subsequent
>   classifiers focus more on difficult cases

But still I'm getting this error.

In the [code examples I've found](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_adaboost_multiclass.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-adaboost-multiclass-py), even on sklearn's website with how to use AdaBoost and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What shape does `train_pdf_y` have?

Comment: @yatu It's (236821, 6). I think it's not clear from my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to perform a [Multi-Output classification problem](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#multi-output-problems), given the shape of `y`, otherwise it does not make sense that you are feeding and n-dimensional `y` to `adaclf.fit(train_pdf_x, train_pdf_y)`.

So assuming that is the case, the problem is that indeed Scikit-Learn's [DecisionTreeClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) does support Multi-output problems, this is, `y` inputs with shape `[n_samples, n_outputs]`. However that is not the case for the [AdaBoostClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.fit), given that, from the documentation, the labels must be:

> **y** : array-like of shape = [n_samples]